# Can't sync time on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sync, date-time

I can't sync time and the Windows Time Service isn't showing on services.msc
Already tried:

Tweaking repair software.

Register the W32Time file but the Windows Time service doesn't show up yet.

```
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
```

A different time server on Control Panel > Date and Time > Internet Time:

> An error occurred while Windows was synchronizing.

Performed SFC scan:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix
> some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log

Perfomed a DISM scan
`Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:D:\Sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`

> [==========================100.0%==========================]
> operation was successfully completed.

Performed SFC scan again.

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Which files are corrupt per `%WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`?  Please provide all information in English.

Comment: I've rebooted now and the sfc scan didnt find corrupted files.

Comment: So after you fixed the corrupt system files have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Not yet, can't sync time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could sync time was installing [NetTime](http://www.timesynctool.com/).